# PHP/MySQL - Using Sessions to Report Scores for Athletic League Website

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, session

Thanks to some poignant feedback from helpful folks here as well as plenty of insight and instruction gained from other sources, I've come quite a long way in my quest to create a schedule/standings database for my youth athletics program.  I'm down to one of the final (albeit most important) parts of the process and could use your help identifying flaws in the syntax I'm using to allow schools to report games scores.

Here's the schedule page that I'm using to work this all out:

http://www.parochialathleticleague.org/schedules_test.html

The content is dynamically generated from league data stored in a MySQL table. If you look at the page, you'll see that an icon can be clicked to report the score for each game that has not been documented yet. When a user clicks on one of those icons, I want to send the important data for that game to a separate score reporting page for updating.

Here's the relevant bit of code from the PHP script that's trying to pass that data along via a session:

```
if ($row['home_score'] == '0' && $row['away_score'] == '0') {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['home_team'] = $row['home_score'];
        $_SESSION['away_team'] = $row['away_score'];
        $_SESSION['game_id'] = $row['game_id'];
        $_SESSION['league'] = "test_league";
        echo '<td><a href="report_score.html"><img src="images/report_icon.png" alt="Report Score" /></a></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>' . $row['home_score'] . '<br>' . $row['away_score'] . '</td>';
    }
```

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that I'm not writing the code correctly because the session variables don't appear to send at all. When the score reporting page is loaded, the user is supposed to see the two team names (home and away) generated from the session, but instead they're missing altogether. Here's a link to the score reporting page for a better idea:

http://www.parochialathleticleague.org/report_score.html

Also, here's the bit of code within that page that's supposed to recall the session variables:

```
<p class="p5 results">Enter Game Results</p>

<div class="form2">
<label><?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['away_team']; ?></label>
<span>                                                    
<input type="text" name="away_team" />
</span>
</div>

<div class="form2">
<label><?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['home_team']; ?></label>
<span>                                                    
<input type="text" name="home_team" />
</span>
</div>
```

Finally, here's the code of the script itself that is supposed to process the form and update the MySQL table accordingly:

```
<?php

// Connect to the database:
require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Start the session:
session_start();

// Validate the school:
if (empty($_POST['school'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter your school.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif ($_POST['school'] != ($_SESSION['home_team'] || $_SESSION['away_team']) {
    echo "Your school does not match one of the two on file for this game.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $school = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['school']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the password:
if (empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter your password.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['pass']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the away score:
if (empty($_POST['away_team'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter the away score.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['$away_team']) || $_POST['$away_team'] < 0 ) {
    echo "You entered an invalid score for the away team.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $away_score = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['away_score']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// Validate the home score:
if (empty($_POST['home_team'])) {
    echo "You forgot to enter the home score.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['$home_team']) || $_POST['$home_team'] < 0 ) {
    echo "You entered an invalid score for the home team.<br>";
    $validate = 'false';
} else {
    $home_team = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST['home_score']));
    $validate = 'true';
}

// If all conditions are met, process the form:
if ($validate != 'false') {
    $q1 = "SELECT school_id FROM user_schools WHERE (school_name='$school' AND pass='$pass')";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r1);
    if ($num == 1) {
        // Get the row for the game ID:
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($_SESSION['game_id'], MYSQLI_NUM);
        // Perform an UPDATE query to modify the game scores:
        $q2 = "UPDATE" . $_SESSION['league'] . "SET home_score='$home_score', away_score='$away_score' WHERE game_id=$row[0]";
        $r2 = mysqli_query($db, $q2);
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db) == 1) {
            header("Location: schedules_test.html");
        } else {
            echo "The scores could not be reported due to a system error. Apologies for the inconvenience. If this problem continues, please contact us directly.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Your school and password combination do not match those on file for this game. If you forgot your password, please contact Will Bryant directly.";
    }       

}

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Sorry to throw so much code out there. I've been learning these languages on the fly and trying my best to soak in as much instruction as possible. I believe I'm heading in the right direction with this process, but undoubtedly have made some mistakes with the syntax (minor or significant, I'm not entirely sure).

Clicking the submit button leads to a blank white page, but it was already clear enough that there was trouble afoot when the team names wouldn't load on the reporting page.

***Where exactly am I going wrong in the examples above, specifically as it relates to passing the session data along?*** Any and all advice, insight, critiques, name calling, etc. would be much appreciated!

Comment: You must use `session_start();` before any output was sent to the browser.

Comment: I believe I have (as demonstrated in the examples above), or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it' quite hard to comprehend such a wall of code at once, I have a **strong** feeling that you are using sessions not on the purpose. Try to rewrite your code, utilizing **regilar** approach used by everyone else:

Every page that have to display some data stored in database, have to receive a row identifier via GET parameter, and query a database using it.

While sessions (in your case) have to be used for the authorization purpose only.

Comment: I was under the impression that GET commands were only an option if the variables were being passed from a form.  Will look into it further.  Thanks!

Comment: Quite contrary, it's only POST variables can be passed from a form. While GET variable is the main method of passing a variable. even google uses it for the search: `http://google.com/search?q=GET` notice that `q` variable. It can be added to any hyperlink `<a href=table.php?team=1>View details</a>`

Comment: Thanks, again. This is actually exactly what I was wanting to do. I just thought that sessions were the way to go about it.

Comment: Sessions will lead you to a great confuse. They are **global** for the site, so, opening 2 tabs with different pages will result in an awful mess. While GET variables are unique for the page. And thus lets you to bookmark a page, or to send a link to a friend!

Comment: Last question for you: The page I'm passing the variables to has a .html extension.  I have set .html extensions to accept PHP via CPanel (if that's the correct way of phrasing it).  Am I still okay to use the URL method, or will I need to rename the .html page to a .php extension?

Comment: In general extension doesn't matter. But I would rename, as some servers or routers may behave differently for them.

Comment: Sorry, one more: Do you see any problem with the following syntax included in the echo command - `<a href="report_score.html?league=test_league&game_id=" . $row['game_id'] . "&home_team=" . $row['home_team'] . "&away_team=" . $row['away_team']>` - Something about is breaking the page and cutting off the rest of the function.

Comment: the very ending `>` looks not in place. looks like need to be `$row['away_team'].">";` or something

Comment: Thought the same, but that doesn't help the problem.  Will experiment further.